# Receive NaN for variables in a list after iterating through it

Tags: python, loops, nan, yahoo, stock

I have a list of shares that make up an ETF. I have formatted the tickers into a list and have named this variable **assets**

```
print(assets)
['AUD', 'CRWD', 'SPLK', 'OKTA', 'AVGO', 'CSCO', 'NET', 'ZS', 'AKAM', 'FTNT', 'BAH', 'CYBR', 'CHKP', 'BA/', 'VMW', 'PFPT', 'PANW', 'VRSN', 'FFIV', 'JNPR', 'LDOS', '4704', 'FEYE', 'QLYS', 'SAIC', 'RPD', 'HO', 'MIME', 'SAIL', 'VRNS', 'ITRI', 'AVST', 'MANT', 'TENB', '053800', 'ZIXI', 'OSPN', 'RDWR', 'ULE', 'MOBL', 'ATEN', 'TUFN', 'RBBN', 'NCC', 'KRW', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'USD']
```

I use the following **for loop** to iterate through the list and pull historical data from yahoo

```
for i in assets:
    try:
          df[i] = web.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']
   except RemoteDataError:
    print(f'{i}')
    continue
```

I am returned with:

```
BA/
4704
H0
053800
KRW
JPY
```

Suggesting these assets cannot be found on yahoo finance. I understand this is the case and accept that.

When I look for the stocks that have theoretically been found (e.g. `df['FEYE']`) on yahoo finance I get the following.

`0    NaN 1    NaN 2    NaN 3    NaN 4    NaN 5    NaN 6    NaN 7    NaN 8    NaN 9    NaN 10   NaN 11   NaN 12   NaN 13   NaN 14   NaN 15   NaN 16   NaN 17   NaN 18   NaN 19   NaN 20   NaN 21   NaN 22   NaN 23   NaN 24   NaN 25   NaN 26   NaN 27   NaN 28   NaN 29   NaN 30   NaN 31   NaN 32   NaN 33   NaN 34   NaN 35   NaN 36   NaN 37   NaN 38   NaN 39   NaN 40   NaN 41   NaN 42   NaN 43   NaN 44   NaN 45   NaN 46   NaN 47   NaN 48   NaN`
Name: FEYE, dtype: float64

When I proceed normally with just one share

(e.g. `CSCO = web.DataReader(assets[5], data_source='yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']`)

It is all ok.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you!

[image: Edit: Image of NaN for reference]

[image: Edit: df.head()]

Comment: I cannot replicate error for 'FEYE'. What date range are You trying to retrieve?

Comment: I had a start date of 2016,1,1 and end date of 2020,6,1. From my experience it will default to the largest window within that time frame in any case. I also thought maybe that’s an issue, but I’ve used the same date variables CSCO example.

Comment: I've just downloaded 'FEYE' data in loop as in Your code, so what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for trying ipj.I still receive a list of NaN, I've uploaded a photo of the error. Perhaps I'm calling the wrong thing, maybe the image will help.

Comment: In my `df ` index is just date not integer. Can you share result of `df.head()` ?

Comment: I've added a photo of df.head(). I think the error is in my loop df[i] as I already have the initial data frame named df, so I want to create a new data frame with the columns being the stocks and the rows being the date with the adjusted close. Do I need to have a new data frame in the loop function?

Comment: I've summarised all my findings in answer. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is reproducible testing example of code and output.
If You have existing dataframe named `df` then new data is incompatible in terms of index and maybe column names.
Creating new dataframe is needed but outside the loop. Each itertation creates new column with ticker data.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError

assets=['AUD', 'CRWD', 'SPLK', 'OKTA', 'AVGO', 'CSCO', 'NET', 'ZS', 'AKAM', 'FTNT', 'BAH', 'CYBR', 'CHKP', 'BA/', 'VMW', 'PFPT', 'PANW', 'VRSN', 'FFIV', 'JNPR', 'LDOS', '4704', 'FEYE', 'QLYS', 'SAIC', 'RPD', 'HO', 'MIME', 'SAIL', 'VRNS', 'ITRI', 'AVST', 'MANT', 'TENB', '053800', 'ZIXI', 'OSPN', 'RDWR', 'ULE', 'MOBL', 'ATEN', 'TUFN', 'RBBN', 'NCC', 'KRW', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'USD']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in assets:
    try:
        print(f'Try: {i}')
        df[i] = web.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo')['Adj Close']
    except RemoteDataError as r:
        print(f'Try: {i}: {r}')
        continue
```

result:

```
Try: AUD
Try: CRWD
Try: SPLK
Try: OKTA
Try: AVGO
Try: CSCO
Try: NET
Try: ZS
Try: AKAM
Try: FTNT
Try: BAH
Try: CYBR
Try: CHKP
Try: BA/
Try: BA/: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA//history?period1=1435975200&period2=1593741599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<html>\n<meta charset=\'utf-8\'>\n<script>\nvar u=\'https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3a%2f%2ffinance.yahoo.com%2fquote%2fBA%2f%2fhistory%3fperiod1%3d1435975200%26period2%3d1593741599%26interval%3d1d%26frequency%3d1d%26filter%3dhistory\';\nif(window!=window.top){\n  document.write(\'<p>Content is currently unavailable.</p><img src="//geo.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757039&t=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'&_R=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+\'&err=404&err_url=\'+u+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>\');\n}else{\n  window.location.replace(u);\n}\n</script>\n<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3a%2f%2ffinance.yahoo.com%2fquote%2fBA%2f%2fhistory%3fperiod1%3d1435975200%26period2%3d1593741599%26interval%3d1d%26frequency%3d1d%26filter%3dhistory\'"></noscript>\n</html>\n'
Try: VMW
Try: PFPT
Try: PANW
Try: VRSN
Try: FFIV
Try: JNPR
Try: LDOS
Try: 4704
Try: 4704: No data fetched for symbol 4704 using YahooDailyReader
Try: FEYE
Try: QLYS
Try: SAIC
Try: RPD
Try: HO
Try: HO: No data fetched for symbol HO using YahooDailyReader
Try: MIME
Try: SAIL
Try: VRNS
Try: ITRI
Try: AVST
Try: MANT
Try: TENB
Try: 053800
Try: 053800: No data fetched for symbol 053800 using YahooDailyReader
Try: ZIXI
Try: OSPN
Try: RDWR
Try: ULE
Try: MOBL
Try: ATEN
Try: TUFN
Try: RBBN
Try: NCC
Try: KRW
Try: KRW: No data fetched for symbol KRW using YahooDailyReader
Try: EUR
Try: JPY
Try: JPY: No data fetched for symbol JPY using YahooDailyReader
Try: GBP
```

Please note there are 2 types of error:

- when ticker does not exists, for example "HO"
- when resulting URL is wrong due to "/" in "BA/"

Head of result set dataframe `df.head()`:

```
                  AUD  CRWD       SPLK  OKTA  ...   NCC  EUR         GBP        USD
Date                                          ...                                  
2015-11-03  51.500000   NaN  57.139999   NaN  ...  3.45  NaN  154.220001  13.608685
2015-12-22  55.189999   NaN  54.369999   NaN  ...  3.48  NaN  148.279999  13.924644
2015-12-23  55.560001   NaN  56.509998   NaN  ...  3.48  NaN  148.699997  14.146811
2015-12-24  55.560001   NaN  56.779999   NaN  ...  3.48  NaN  149.119995  14.324224
2015-12-28  56.270000   NaN  57.660000   NaN  ...  3.48  NaN  148.800003  14.057305

[5 rows x 43 columns]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thank you ipj. I believe the error was that I was not appending to a new empty data frame, where you have df = pd.DataFrame(), is what I was missing. Thanks for your help and patience.